# enum list with pre-selected multiselect form

Tags: php, mysql, enums, selected

Ok, so I am new to this sort of thing and am building a small site for work that has profiles for employees. I am working on a way to edit profiles, and when someone goes to the "edit" page, I need all of the already used values to be pre-selected.

When I have a dropdown based on an enum list, it works just fine

## Example

```
<?php

$table_name = "agents";
$column_name = "AssignedABC";

echo "<select name=\"$column_name\"><option>Select one</option>";
$q = "SELECT COLUMN_TYPE FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
    WHERE TABLE_NAME = '$table_name' AND COLUMN_NAME = '$column_name'";
$r = mysqli_query($con, $q);

$row = mysqli_fetch_array($r);

$enumList = explode(",", str_replace("'", "", substr($row['COLUMN_TYPE'], 5, (strlen($row['COLUMN_TYPE'])-6))));
foreach($enumList as $value)
    echo '<option value="'.$value.'" '.(($value==$rows[AssignedABC])?'selected="selected"':"").'>'.$value.'</option>';

echo "</select>";
?>
```

The problem happens when there is a multi-select box. I cannot get it to pre-select all/any of the existing selections from the database.

## Problem Code

```
<?php

$table_name = "agents";
$column_name = "Designations";

echo "<select multiple name='Designations[]'>";
$q = "SELECT COLUMN_TYPE FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
    WHERE TABLE_NAME = '$table_name' AND COLUMN_NAME = '$column_name'";
$r = mysqli_query($con, $q);

$row = mysqli_fetch_array($r);

$enumList = explode(",", str_replace("'", "", substr($row['COLUMN_TYPE'], 5, (strlen($row['COLUMN_TYPE'])-6))));
foreach($enumList as $value)

    echo '<option value="'.$value.'" '.(($value==$rows[Designations])?'selected="selected"':"").'>'.$value.'</option>';

echo "</select>";
?>
```

Any sort of help/guidance would be much appreciated :)

## Edit/Update

```
<?php

$table_name = "agents";
$column_name = "Designations";
$csvString = $rows['Designations'];
$des = explode(",", $csvString);

echo "<select multiple name='Designations[]'>";
$q = "SELECT COLUMN_TYPE FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
    WHERE TABLE_NAME = '$table_name' AND COLUMN_NAME = '$column_name'";
$r = mysqli_query($con, $q);

$row = mysqli_fetch_array($r);

$enumList = explode(",", str_replace("'", "", substr($row['COLUMN_TYPE'], 5, (strlen($row['COLUMN_TYPE'])-6))));
foreach ($des as $opt)
foreach($enumList as $value)

    echo '<option value="'.$value.'" '.(($value==$opt)?'selected="selected"':"").'>'.$value.'</option>';

echo "</select>";

?>
```

Everything is properly pre-selecting now.. only there are repeats of every option in the list now. 0_o

## Working Code

```
<?php

$table_name = "agents";
$column_name = "Designations";
$csvString = $rows['Designations'];
$des = explode(",", $csvString);

echo "<select multiple name='Designations[]'>";
$q = "SELECT COLUMN_TYPE FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
    WHERE TABLE_NAME = '$table_name' AND COLUMN_NAME = '$column_name'";
$r = mysqli_query($con, $q);

$row = mysqli_fetch_array($r);

$enumList = explode(",", str_replace("'", "", substr($row['COLUMN_TYPE'], 5, (strlen($row['COLUMN_TYPE'])-6))));

foreach($enumList as $value)

    echo '<option value="'.$value.'" '.((in_array($value, $des))?'selected="selected"':"").'>'.$value.'</option>';

echo "</select>";

?>
```

Comment: do `echo $rows[Designations]` in your foreach()...maybe it is always returning false

Comment: When I include that, after the </select>, within the foreach(), the proper it prints the expected results that should be pre-selecting.

Comment: echo $rows[Designations] does return a list if there are multiple selections - CLV,CHFC,CPCV - so that list, wouldn't match any one of the values. Is there any way to have it check through each possible option in the enum list vs all at once?

Comment: It looks like you're getting closer...continue to debug using `echo`. Ensure `$enumList` and `$des` do not contain any duplicates. If that doesn't work, echo `$value` and `$opt` before every option to see what combinations are getting repeated.

Comment: Found the issue :D

Instead of (($value==$opt) I used ((in_array($value, $des)) and it's working perfectly :D